# Using Node.js for long polling along with Apache

Tags: node.js, cpu-usage, long-polling

I read that Node.js is more CPU intensive than apache. However if I serve only the long polling calls using node.js and the rest using apache, does it still take up as much CPU or will it prove to be beneficial.

I intend to try this out myself but it would be helpful if someone has already done this and has opinions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read that Node.js is more CPU
>   intensive than apache.

Where did you read that? I believe the opposite is true.

> However if I serve only the long
>   polling calls using node.js and the
>   rest using apache, does it still take
>   up as much CPU or will it prove to be
>   beneficial.

The best part of node.js is that is very efficient doing things like long-polling. While Apache/PHP IO blocks. node.js does not have blocking IO.

Answer (score 1):

Long polling doesn't make Node.js use much CPU. It just waits for the event to occur.

Comment: it uses no CPU while it's waiting. the key is that it also uses very little RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Apache (in prefork mode) spawns a process per connection. That is pretty limiting considering the number of processes you can launch and also the size of the process (~21MB). So you'll run out of the max number of processes/RAM pretty fast (whichever hits first).

With node you can easily manage tens of thousands of connections per process with a cheap linux box.